# How do I solve this in excel? I think it's a cumulative rolling percentage problem

Tags: mortgage, loans, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that shows the following columns.

Date, Loan Applications Received, Interest Rate Offered, Cumulative Applications Received, Loans Originated, Average Interest Rate on Originated Loans. Columns that say loans originated and average interest rate on originated loans are blank and I need to fill them out.

I have dates from 12/1/2017 until 12/31/2018 filled in for the date column. I have numbers like 1384, 1875, 1498 etc. listed in the Loan Applications Received Column for each date in the range. Interest rate offered are like 7.46%, 7.51%, and 7.42% etc. and I have one for each date in the range. Cumulative applications are filled in for each date as well.

I am additionally given a second table which shows the days since application received (0,1,2,3...30) and a cumulative percentage of applications resulting in Originated Loans that shows 0.25%, 0.75%, 1.75%...10%. To be clear 0 days corresponds to 0.25% and 30 days corresponds to 10%.

I am looking to find the loans originated by date and the average interest rate on originated loans by date.

Comment: You would use countifs() to count the loans originated between two dates and either averageifs() or sumifs()/count to average the rate.

Comment: How would I correctly structure those formulas?